# My preg_replace string is almost perfect but I'm having one small trouble

Tags: php, regex

trying to get my preg_replace statement to work, which it does for the most part, except for a few variations.

```
<?php
$string = "10vdc";
if (preg_match("/(^[0-9]+[0-9])+[v | a]/i",$string)) {
    echo "yes!";
    $string = preg_replace("/^[0-9]+[0-9]/","$0 ",$string);
}
if (preg_match("/[v | a][ac | dc]/i",$string)) {
    echo "<br>yes2!";
    $string = preg_replace("/([\d | \s][v | a])([ac|dc])/i","$1 $2",$string);
}
echo "<br>";
echo $string;
?>
```

If my string is 10vdc, 10 vdc, 10vac, or 10 vac my regex works (it should print out 10 v dc or 10 v ac, respectively) but if my string is 10adc, 10 adc, 10aac, or 10 aac my echo returns only 10 adc or 10 aac, respectively. I've been working on tutorials all morning and I'm starting to get the hang of this but this is stumping me!

Obviously if you'd like to try it just change the $string value.

Thanks for any help! You're all the best.

Comment: You really don't need to do a `preg_match()` first before the `preg_replace()`.

Comment: Okay, once I get it working I'll probably remove the `pref_match`s. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. It has to do with the space after the or (`|`) designator.

So what was:
`/([\d | \s][v | a])([ac|dc])/i`

should read:
`/([\d|\s][v|a])([ac|dc])/i`.